# Google App Engine - Cloud Debugger availability?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-debugger

At [Google I/O Keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtLJPvx7-ys#t=7270) this year, they announced **[Cloud Debugger](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.fr/2014/06/enabling-developers-to-tame-production-systems-in-the-cloud.html)**.

Is there any specs?
Because I can't find this button on my Google App Engine Developers Console.
My app is a classic GWT/Java app packaged in a WAR.
The source code is on GitHub and it's linked to my Developers Console "Repository connected".

Do I need to package my app with [module](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/)?
Or do something else?

THX

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2015, the Java Cloud Debugger (Beta) is supported on Managed VMs, [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-debugger/setting-up-on-compute-engine), and [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-debugger/setting-up-on-app-engine). The Cloud Debugger is enabled automatically for Java applications running on App Engine, including those running on Managed VMs.

Support for other languages, including Python, Node.js, and Go, is coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

You have to express interest in it, then they might send you a sign up link. It's not currently available in the Developers Console by default.

The link was in the console/debugging section but is currently showing as "signups closed".

Answer (score 1):

Java Cloud Debugger is in public preview now. At the moment Cloud Debugger is only supported with [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/).

You don't need to do anything special beyond linking or pushing the Git repository. If you deploy your app with Managed VMs, the debugger will be available in Google Developers Console --> Source Code --> Browse (look for an icon with an eye on a top right corner).